# Having issues in moving from one activity to another using a button in Andriod Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a sound board app with multiple actives with their own buttons and sounds. I cant seem to get the hang of moving from one activity to another using a button. The first activity moves just fine to the second, but the second doesn't move to the third and suddenly closes the app. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my code for the first activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnMove;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnMove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMove);
    btnMove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            finish();


        }
    });
 }
}
```

Here is my code for the second activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnMove2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    btnMove2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMove2);
    btnMove2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent b = newIntent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            finish();

    }
});

  }

 }
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you are finishing activities, so there is no parent Try removing `finish();`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried that at first and no dice.

Comment: post your logcat from the crash.

Comment: Could you edit and  add in the code for the 3rd activity. Also it may help if you include the log.

Comment: Intent b = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);  make space between new and intent

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown appears to work fine *(albeit that using* `finish()` *is not what would normally be done)*. However you haven't shown the 3rd activity and that is likely where the issue is. It is also highly likely, assuming that exactly the same happened when `finish()` was removed from both **`MainActivity`** and **`Main2Activity`** that the App is crashing. It would be nearly impossible to determine why without the log and the code for the 3rd activity (including the layout XML, which may or may not be relevant).

One issue that would result in something similar to what you describe, is if you haven't added the 3rd activity to the manifest. This would result in an unexpected error and the App crashing with something along the lines of:

```
06-09 08:35:01.628 23844-23844/mjt.so44446139 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mjt.so44446139, PID: 23844
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {mjt.so44446139/mjt.so44446139.Activity3}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
        at mjt.so44446139.Activity2$1.onClick(Activity2.java:23)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The above indicating an **`ActivityNotFoundException`**. If this is the case then you need to add **Main3Activity** to the manifest (you would have done this for the 2nd Activity).

### **Regarding** **`finish()`**

If you have `finish()` coded after you start an activity via `startActivity`, then that activity will not be returned to as it has been finished. It will return to instead to that activities parent, if there is one.

Thus:
If `finish()` is in the first activity then that activity will not be returned to (clicking the devices back button from 2nd activity will finish the App).

If `finish()` is ONLY in the 2nd activity then it will not be returned to from the 3rd activity. However, returning from the 3rd (e.g. clicking the device's back button) will return to the 1st activity.

If `finish()` is in both the first and 2nd activity then neither will be returned to, thus clicking the device's back button will finish the App.

The normal use of `finish()` is to code it when you are done with an activity (not moving to another). Hence in the 3rd activity there is a line that resets the button's text to done. If `finish()` is un-commented then this will act to finish the activity and return to the 2nd (assuming it hasn't been finished).

### Example Code

The following code may assist you in understanding or perhaps even fixing your issue (it should resemble your code quite closely):

It consists of 3 activities all with a button and currently with `finish()` commented out. They all use the same layout, which includes a Button and a TextView. The Textview is set to reflect the activity's name. As it is, it should reflect what you appear to want. That is clicking the button from the MainActivity takes you to the second. Clicking the button on the 2nd Activity takes you to the third (clicking on the button in the third does nothing).

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView msg = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.message);
        msg.setText(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        Button nextbutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);

        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity2**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button nextbutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
        TextView msg = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.message);
        msg.setText(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity3**

```
public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button nextbutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
        nextbutton.setText("Done");
        TextView msg = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.message);
        msg.setText(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The layout used for all 3 is (noting that `tools:context="mjt.so44446139.MainActivity"` would have to be changed, this is the default *Blank Activity layout with the button added and with an id given to the TextView*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mjt.so44446139.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The manifest is (main thing is that both Activity2 and Activity3 have been added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mjt.so44446139">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity3">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: wow Thank you for the detailed explanation I will implement what you have said first thing tomorrow. I will also update the question with the third activity and log files.